# Author dropdown

Tags: author

Is there a way to only show certain member groups in the Author dropdown per channel?

I know you can prevent a member group from being displayed in there using the Member Group settings. However, I need them to be available in some channels.

Here's my issue.

I'm using CartThrob, and I have a 'Members' group.
'Members' are the 'authors' of their associated order entries. So, the 'members' group needs to be visible in the authors dropdown.

However in my blog, I don't want a mile long author dropdown. I just want to be able to select members from the 'Bloggers' member group.

If I prevent the 'Members' group from being displayed in the dropdown, when I hit submit on a member-authored order entry, I get an invalid member error.

Are there any suggestions for doing something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Does the "Members" group have permissions to edit the Blog in the channel settings?

Comment: You mean the member group settings? Nope.

Comment: Yes, member group settings... sorry. Sounds like a bug then no? If member group isn't set to have access to channel, it shouldn't show in the author list. Might ping EL with bug report.

Comment: Oh. Interesting. I thought that might be the case but wasn't sure. Thanks.

Comment: You could probably hack the display code query to limit the list based on membe rgroup channel permissions.